# How to form a Double with an Integer and Fractional parts

Tags: c, swift, floating-point, double, fractions

I am given two values, the integer and the fractional parts of a double. What is the best way to form the double value? Essentially, it would be the opposite of `modf()`.

I'm doing this in swift, but any mathematical way is what I'm looking for.

```
let integer = 12
let fractional = 34
let d = ???(12, 34) // 12.34
```

Comment: you may also look for `NSNumberFormatter`

Comment: That is not the opposite of `modf`. `modf` gives the fraction portion as a fraction. You have it as an integer. Is that integer always 100 times the fraction? Or could it be 789 for .789? If so, how do we know if 34 is for .34 or .034? What do you want to do about the fact that 12.34 is not representable in binary floating-point? Who gave you this integer and fractional part as integers, and why are they being mean to you?

Comment: The fraction is meaningless without saying what it is a fraction *of*. How do we know `34` isnt `034` or `0034`?

Comment: As the example shows, the fractional portion is the number immediately after the decimal. 1 => 0.1, 12 => 0.12, 123 -> 0.123, etc

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: How would you express the fractional portion of `12.03` as an integer, and how would that be different from the fractional portion of `12.3`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good point, but I only am using the API, not defining it.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: What is this API?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not defending the API. I'm sorry people downvote the question, not like I can just tell the other team to change their code in the past because SO doesn't approve. It's internal and ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general case you have to find the number of digits are there in the fraction part. So I am assuming that x as integer part and y as fractional part. Then you have to divide y by 10 to the power of number of digits in y. And then you have to add x to the updated y value.

Here is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    int count = 0;
    int z = y;
    while(z>0)
    {
        count+=1;
        z = z/10;
    }
    float ans = 0;
    ans = (double)x + (double)y/pow(10,count);
    printf("%f",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

If x and y are also considered as float there is even a better solution. Thanks to Joël Hecht

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    double x,y;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&y);
    while(y>=1)
    {
        y = y/10.0;
    }
    printf("%lf",x+y);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S :- You have to take care if the number given is negative.

Comment: There must be a way to optimize a bit this algorithm : `z` and `y` have the same value and are both divided by the same power of 10 ; the only difference is that `y` is casted to `double` before the operation.